# Send back value from controller when submit form codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-form-helper

here is a question that I am not able to find a way to do it. At the home view, I have a php section that will echo out if users input is just signed in when they submit form. But when I am doing this, it will give out a undefined error, because that controller is not yet executed. 
This is my home view.

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?> 
<?php echo $sign_in_results;?>
<?php include('forms/forms.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

This is my sign in controller, will get execute when submit pressed, the modal will return true or false.

```
 function form_sign_in_controller(){
    $this->load->model("form_sign_in"); 
    $database_insert_results = $this->form_sign_in->check_user_detail_with_db();
    $data['sign_in_results']= $database_insert_results;
    $template = $this->load->View('main_view', $data);
 }
```

I tried to use if(isset()).. The error is gone, but that section does not echo out anything. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: In your main controller which represents the form view, set a default value for your variable as: `$data['sign_in_results']= '';`

Comment: It does work, but it will add extra content to the top of the existing page. So there will be two header bars, because you load the view once again.

Comment: is there anyway to keep the current view, and refresh only a section?

Comment: This is a wrong way, but you can echo off the errors by `echo @$sign_in_results;`

Answer (score 0):

- validate the data that comes from your sign in form. Never pass data from a form directly into a database query.
- validating the data will tell you if the form has correct values. if it does not, then show the form again.
- form data is validated - query your database
- there are 3 possible results - you got a match OR you did not get a match OR there was an error. Check for these 3 different conditions, and then show the appropriate view.